# When will the next episode of Starcraft II be released and will there be an add-on for the current Wings of Liberty?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I understand the plan correctly, Blizzard wants to release three separate games (each one for mainly one race). Did Blizzard mention a general plan in which intervals they wanted to release the three packages?

Are there informations if the current Wings of Liberty (or maybe all of the packages) will have expansions like Brood War? Will they be released before the next "main" game?

In general words: How many games will be released (that we currently know of, of course) in the series of Starcraft II?

<del>In general words: How many games do I have to purchase to get the whole story.</del>

**In more detail:**

As already stated in the comments, the two following expansions will probably be expansion priced, but full scale single player games at least (*thanks for this information already*).

Due to this "full scaling", I was asking myself if Blizzard would offer real expansions for each of the three sets and if there was information to this point available.

Comment: 0 if you use youtube/wikipedia...

Comment: ok, I mean if I want to get the whole story - playing myself.

Comment: As far I know there will be three parts. It's not confirmed whether the two other parts are expansion or standalone games

Comment: @Wai The Executive Vice President of Game Design at Blizzard [seems to expect](http://www.starcraft-source.com/article/news/view/?id=261) an expansion price point.

Comment: Are you asking whether the next two releases will be an expansion or a whole game of Starcraft just flavored differently with different missions? I'm going to assume that it is an expansion, it would be silly to make someone buy the whole game again with a different single player package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the literal questions in your post:

**When will the next episode of Starcraft II be released?**

The current theory is 18 months in between episodes, "maybe." For example [Chris Sigaty (lead producer) said in an interview](http://www.shacknews.com/featuredarticle.x?id=1341):

> We're estimating about 18 months from
>   release of Wings of Liberty to when
>   the next one comes out. That's purely
>   speculative, honestly. Historically,
>   it's taken us about a year-WarCraft
>   III: The Frozen Throne is a good
>   example-but you'll see the sum-total
>   package [in Wings of Liberty] has
>   raised the bar and there's a lot more
>   to do with StarCraft II's expansions.
>   I think 18 months is probably fairly
>   accurate.

**Will there be an add-on for the current Wings of Liberty?**

As much as we'd all love to see more content in those possibly-18-months gaps, there have been no announcements of additional expansions or addons. There will of course be minor patches to address balance and fix bugs, and it would not surprise me if Blizzard released new maps though.

**Edit after Heart of the Swarm was released:**

SC2: HotS was actually released 2 years, 8 months after WoL. Therefore, spot-on with Blizzard's estimate of "Soon™."

Comment: As this answer is more to the point of my posed questions, I think it deserves to be the accepted answer. Nonetheless I'd like to point to wormintrude's answer which gives a lot of additional information information and metainformation.

Answer (score 11):

StampedeXV,

There's several parts to your question. I will try to address them all in the most thorough manner.
First and foremost, "How many games will I have to purchase to get the whole story ?".
If there is one thing I've learnt about Blizzard in the 12+ years that I've been playing their games, is that there is no such thing as "getting the whole story".
With Blizzard games comes lore. In the shape of game storyline, books, comics, etc, etc. They live off selling their games, and they can only continue to do so by means of expanding the corresponding 'universes'. If what you want is a story with a set beginning, middle and end, you will have to look elsewhere.

Starcraft II is (at least initially) planned as a three part release.
Part 1 is the current storyline, Wings of Liberty. Part 2 will be Heart of the Swarm and will focus on the Zerg. Although the storyline has not been announced, there are expectations that it will revolve around Kerrigan (disclaimer: this is pure speculation, mods please feel free to edit it out). The last part, Legacy of the Void, will center around the Protoss.
HotS and LotV will be release in the form of *expansions*, which leads to believe that the price tag will be significantly lower than for WoL.
This is not new in the Blizzard way of doing things, if you go back a tad more than a decade, you will remember that the original Starcraft was made up of episodes. They did not use expansions back then (that is until BW), but again, expansions were not common back then and DLCs were hiding far beyond the horizon.

From where I stand, I choose to view Blizzard games as an experience. And indeed, one to be savoured. If you are, however, in desperate need for lore, I would advise you to check out the Starcraft related literature available. Amazon would be a good place to start perhaps.
And if your hunger is still not satisfied, you could also join the forums and ride the creative wave. Many a member discuss potential story lines and plot changes there, and from time to time they get rewarded with some sort of contest (last one had a GTX460 as a prize if I am not mistaken).

Hope I gave you the answer you were looking for. If you need more details, ask, and the community shall see to it that you get them.

Cheers!

Comment: really nice answer.